# mapping selected rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

this should be easy but i can't get it done without adding more columns. I have the following dataframe df:

```
Region ID    Type Value 
A      2045  X    111
A      2045  Y    222
A      2045  Z    333
B      2045  X    NaN
B      2045  Y    NaN
B      2045  Z    NaN
```

I am trying to fill in the NaN with values from the concatenation of ID and Type. Only values in Region B are missing.

Tried the following:

df['Lookup'] = df['ID'] + df['Type'] <-----Add new lookup column

df_map= df[df['Region']=='A'][['Value','Lookup']] <----create another df with valid values for mapping purposes

.map(df_map.set_index('Lookup')['Value']) <---how do i replace NaN with this code?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) for replace `NaN`s by mapping:

```
df['Lookup'] = df['ID'].astype(str) + df['Type']
df_map= df.loc[df['Region']=='A', ['Value','Lookup']].set_index('Lookup')['Value']
print (df_map)
Lookup
2045X    111.0
2045Y    222.0
2045Z    333.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64

df['Value'] = df['Value'].combine_first(df['Lookup'].map(df_map))
print (df)
  Region    ID Type  Value Lookup
0      A  2045    X  111.0  2045X
1      A  2045    Y  222.0  2045Y
2      A  2045    Z  333.0  2045Z
3      B  2045    X  111.0  2045X
4      B  2045    Y  222.0  2045Y
5      B  2045    Z  333.0  2045Z
```

Same solution with `MultiIndex` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) by 2 columns `ID` and `Type`:

```
df_map= df.loc[df['Region']=='A', ['ID','Type','Value']].set_index(['ID','Type'])['Value']
print (df_map)
ID    Type
2045  X       111.0
      Y       222.0
      Z       333.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64

new = df.join(df_map.rename('new'), on=['ID','Type'])['new']
df['Value'] = df['Value'].combine_first(new)
print (df)
  Region    ID Type  Value
0      A  2045    X  111.0
1      A  2045    Y  222.0
2      A  2045    Z  333.0
3      B  2045    X  111.0
4      B  2045    Y  222.0
5      B  2045    Z  333.0
```

Comment: sorry just to addon: what if the Region column is not sorted? Meaning it can be A, B, A, B, A, B

Comment: It is no necessary, because filter columns by condition `df['Region']=='A'`